# When I plug in USB extension my mouse is deactivated

Tags: mouse

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, my mouse/keyboard is a Logitech K350.
I have an extension for the USB (since I am tired of trying to see the USB port in the dark below desktop level I use an extension/USB cord for it). When I plug in the extension cord the mouse becomes frozen/unresponsive. When I unplug the extension cord the mouse works again. Any ideas? All batteries are new and charged.

Comment: If the box (particularly the PSU) is getting old; I've experienced problems before with extension cords because the PSU was barely providing the power before extension cord is added, with extension cord the power supplied is below reliable threshold. The fix is a new PSU in the older box (though removing other hardware thus reducing the load on the PSU will also work).  This may not be your issue